# How do I use setFilter in Mapbox correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mapbox

I'm trying to filter a layer i've added to the map from a geojson file. Every time i click a button to filter the map, it hides the entire layer rather than individual elements on that layer. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong/not understanding about .setFilter()

I've tried multiple ways of using the filter such as map.setFilter('allBuildings', ['==', 'properties.name', 'buildingone']);

However, it still hides the entire layer. I would be grateful if anyone could push me in the right direction. Thanks

Here I add the source and layer to the map which all works fine.

```
map.addSource('buildings', {type: 'geojson', data: '/buildings.geojson'});

map.addLayer({
  "id": "allBuildings",
  "type": "symbol",
  "source": "buildings",
  "layout": {
    "icon-image": "marker-building",
    "icon-size": 0.25
  }
});
```

I then try filtering the layer by using

```
map.setFilter('allBuildings', ['>', 'properties.height', '30']);
```

At this point, it hides the layer rather than just the objects that have a greater height than 30.

Here is part of my geojson file.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "buildingone",
        "height": "52",
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          114.1454573,
          22.2760386
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is it required that you keep your height values in string format? If so, you may need to convert this to a numeric in order to use the numeric operator `>`. Also, I think your filter can reference the just the height and not 'properties.height', like: 
`map.setFilter('allBuildings', ['>', 'height', 30]);`

Comment: I think you have to use a `get` expression to access the property. So `map.setFilter('allBuildings', ['>', ['get', 'height'], 30]`. More here: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#get

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing the responses from the comments you should use this command

```
map.setFilter('allBuildings', ['>', ['to-number', ['get', 'height']], 30])
```

Retrieve a property value with a [`get` expression](https://docs.mapbox.com/style-spec/reference/expressions/#get). Then convert the retrieved string [to number](https://docs.mapbox.com/style-spec/reference/expressions/#types-to-number) and finally [compare](https://docs.mapbox.com/style-spec/reference/expressions/#%3E). It works in MapLibre as well.